# MSMQ OnReceiveCompleted method - Queue.Body throws InvaliOperationException

Tags: exception, msmq, throws

My MSMQ is located on a remote machine. 
My code is as follows,

```
    private void OnReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Messaging.Message msg = _queue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);

        FireReceiveEvent(msg.Body); // Here msg.Body throws exception

        _queue.BeginReceive();
    }
```

I'm running this as a windows service, not sure if that makes a difference. But msg.Body throws a InvaliOperationException.

Infact most of the msg's properties are throwing exceptions. Any idea?
[here is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upxAI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try casting source parameter as MessageQueue

```
private void MessageQueueReceiveCompleted(Object source, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncReceive)
{
   try
   {
      //Get a handle to the Message Queue
      MessageQueue messageQueue = (MessageQueue)source;
      Message message = messageQueue.EndReceive(asyncReceive.AsyncResult);

      if (message != null)
         {
            ProcessMsmqMessage(message.Body);
         }

   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Exception err = new Exception(String.Format("Error in QueueListener: {0}. Detail: {1}", queueName, e.Message), e);
      OnListeningError(err);
   }
   finally{
      messageQueue.BeginReceive();
   }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. The only difference is my _queue is a class member, whereas you are getting it from source.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So after much work and reading, and banging my head against the wall, I found what the problem was.

REMOTE queues work very differently than local private queues.
You may ask, why? Well... this is probably a deficiency in MS' API.

Remote queues are very icky. They do not support a lot of feature that are available for regular local queues.

For example, in a remote queue unless it's transactional, you cannot do a BeginPeek. You cannot even check message.Body, because it would throw an error.

But that's not all. You cannot even accidentally subscribe to an event like OnPeekCompleted (even if you don't do a BeginPeek). The entire MessageQueue object goes crazy when you do that.

This silly reason was the reason for my headache.